# Compiled version of (Norm/@coordinates)

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

Here I define (`NormCoordinates`).

```
NormCoordinates[coordinates_]:=Norm/@coordinates;
NormCoordinates[{{2.2,4.4},{5.5,6.6},{-6.7,1.3},{-2.7,-0.3}}]

(* {4.91935, 8.59127, 6.82495, 2.71662} *)
```

As in the example above, I plan to only use it on elements with the Head `Real`. 
I notice (`Norm`) can't be compiled. Can anyone implement this using `Compile` and lower level functions in a way the runs much faster on a large list?

Comment: No time right now to survey different methods, but I have a feeling compilation won't gain you that much in this case. If it's just the 2-norm you want, you can get an improvement of 50% or so from ``listableNorm = Function[coords, Sqrt@Total[Internal`Square[coords], {2}]];``.

Comment: `Norm[]` is in [this list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/), though.

Comment: Silly me, I checked the list of compileable functions and didn't see it. I also didn't know about Internal`Square.

Comment: If you write it as `listableNorm2 = Function[coords, Sqrt@Total[coords coords, {2}]]` it's not significantly slower than using ``Internal`Square`` (tested using `LocationEquivalenceTest` with 100  timings of 10^6 vectors), but you don't have to use an undocumented function, which generally is scary.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean by *large lists* since any solution is reasonable fast on a list which I think is pretty large. Please find the 2 solutions mentioned by Olek and Sjoerd and a compiled one below

```
normTed[coordinates_] := Norm /@ coordinates;
normSjoerd = Function[coords, Sqrt@Total[coords coords, {2}]];
normOlek = Function[coords, Sqrt@Total[Internal`Square[coords], {2}]];
normPatrick = Compile[{{v, _Real, 1}}, Sqrt[v.v], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];

data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^8, 2}];
First[AbsoluteTiming[#[data]]] & /@ {normTed, normSjoerd, normOlek, normPatrick}

(*
   {9.800536, 5.647508, 5.384156, 4.350411}    
*)
```

As you can see from top to bottom: Readability drops, performance rises. Whether the 5 seconds are really worth the effort is questionable. Maybe you can update your question with information about your real data.

Btw, on my machine the compiled version of `Sqrt[v.v]` is a glimpse faster (.102s) than the compiled version with `Norm[v]`. Therefore, I did not use `Norm` but it is of course compilable as J.M. pointed out.

Comment: I guess the bottom line is that fundamental functions like `Total`, `Sqrt` are already heavily optimized that compiling does little good. WReach had a nice post on [so] arguing against pointless microbenchmarking and micro optimizations... I can't seem to find it now though, but the essence of it is similar to what you said.

Comment: Sometimes, you can gain more temporal efficiency by using v.v (and not computing the Sqrt) and then comparing to the ^2 of what ever you are comparing too.

Comment: @ruebenko Yes, good point. I didn't mention it here, since the question was to calc the Euclidean norm but if one wants to compare lengths, distances, whatever it is alway good to think about whether the sqrt is really necessary.

Comment: The other thing I had thought of was to try ispc with *LibraryLink* (Mike Croucher gives an example for MATLAB [here](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=3988)). I have no time to do that answer for a month or so--do you fancy giving it a try?